# Create database schema using source database without using mysqldump

Tags: mysql

I'm developing SaaS application where every client has it's own database. For every new client I need to create new instance with new database using same schema. Is there any way to clone schema based on source database without using `mysqldump`? `mysqldump` is really slow (it takes nearly 1 minute to create whole schema).

I`m using mysql 5.7 and InnoDB engine.

Comment: Are we talking about strictly metadata clone?

Comment: How about copying ibdata files?

Comment: @Nae I want to create new database with same schema (tables, indexes, keys etc. - without data) as source database.

Comment: @emix Do I need to restart mysql server after coping those files?

Comment: @PiotrNowicki Are you adding `-d` option in your `mysqldump` script?

Comment: @Nae my source database has no data, but I will try `-d` option.

Comment: @Nae Unfortunately times using `-d` option are the same. Is there any possibility to copy database files without using queries from `mysqldump`? I also want to avoid restarting my mysql server.

Comment: I suppose it should be possible with nasty loops and dynamic statements. Can't guarantee any performance gain though.

Comment: @Piotr just try it :) cheers from Płock. If using mysqldump it will be slow. This is by design, tables have to be created, as well as indexes, constraints.